# How to Know your screen time for the whole day in Ubuntu System 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, screen

I wanted to know for how much time the screen of my laptop(with Ubuntu) was 'ON' for the whole day.

I have used 'uptime -p' but it doesn't work if you turned your system off and then later turned ON for use. Hence, it tells for how long the system(not screen) is running from the last time it was turned ON.

Please suggest if there are any other softwares/desktop-apps also.

Comment: So, would this be suitable: (uptime -p) minus (screensaver on) time  and minus time the (screen was blanked)?

Comment: That's a good idea. But I don't know how to do that! @K7AAY

Comment: So, you need to find how to dig out of the logs of Ubuntu when the screen was blanked and unblanked. Calculate the screen-off time based on log data and subtract that from _uptime -p_ . Therefore, searching for which log(s) record that data is your next step, followed by calculating off time based on what you filter from the appropriate log(s).

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools like links below which you can use to measure Screen Time:

[ActivityWatch](https://activitywatch.net/) (Free)

[RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/download_linux) (You need to pay)